# Is there a way to get an Airport Extreme to coexist with a second router offering VPN?

Tags: airport, vpn

Essentially, I want add VPN functionality to my home-office domain so I can access it from  other locations, and allow the occasional other person to access it this way.

Obviously, the two routers need to be daisy-chained together, only one of them should be the DHCP server, and only one of them should connect to my ISP, and so forth. The key question is whether the AirportExtreme can happily do half of the job it was intended to do.

Has anyone here had experience building such a configuration?

Thanks in advance
Josh

Comment: Why exactly do you want two routers installed? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What am I trying to accomplish? Exactly what I wrote in the first paragraph of my question.

I want to keep the Airport Extreme as the WiFi provider because I trust it. Its one drawback is that it doesn't provide VPN services. Hence, I want to augment what I have with something that offers VPN services.

Comment: How did you go with your build? If you want to keep your AE as the wiFi and the other router as a VPN device that can be achieved easily. I have a set up where I have an AE, and two other routers/firewalls.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. You set up your other router as the default gateway for the Airport Extreme, put the Airport extreme in bridging mode via the Airport Utility.

The new router will be connected to your ISP, and have the VPN tunnel set up, depending on which model you choose you will be limited as to what type of tunnel you can set up (GRE, IPSec) or something else, in the case of routers such as FritzBox (which can only set up VPN tunnels to other FritzBox routers.

I would recommend the cheapest 800 series router from CISCO.

Or you could also  run [pfSense](http://www.pfsense.org/) virtually or on a stand alone box which will provide VPN functionality you require.